# How to execute the codes again

Tags: java

this code is correct but i want to add a message for example "good" if the inputted number is greater than 1520 and less than 3999

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class date
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        int x;
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a date ");
        x = in.nextInt();

        while (x < 1520 || x > 3999)
        {
            System.out.println ("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
            System.out.print ("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
            x = in.nextInt();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just have to add a line like `System.out.println("good")` after your while loop. I don't understand how it's related with your question's title...

Comment: okay thank you i dont know where to put that thing so i ask im new in java. ty again :)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add a print statement (ie. `System.out.println("Good");`) after your loop.

***NOTE**: I changed the class name from `date` to `Date`, which is proper Java convention for naming a Class. Please change your file from date.java to Date.java when you use this code (if you copy and paste it, that is) to prevent compilation issues. Class name and filename must match up, case-sensitive), in Java if I recall correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date{
   public static void main (String args []){
      int x;

      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a date ");
      x = in.nextInt();


      while (x < 1520 || x > 3999)
      {
          System.out.println ("Invalid Gregorian Calendar date.");
          System.out.print ("Please Input a valid Gregorian Calendar date: ");
          x = in.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("Good");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please change the class name from `date` to `Date` to promote proper java naming conventions.

Comment: @Takendarkk just did. I didn't want to change OP's code and risk it not running in his IDE, but I'll add a note.

Comment: what if user didnt input a number? what if user input symbols or letters? what will i need to add or do?

Comment: @user3802127 I think that should probably be a different question. But, what I would do, is look into Scanner.hasNextInt() and make that a condition as well before simply saving the result into x. Because if someone types in "Hello" for example, it WILL crash your program at this point.